# Sorting XML file with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file (this is just a snip of it)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   
   <InterfaceHeader Version="1" originationsystem="xxx" systemdate="2024-02-22T14:27:11"  username="xxx" testindicator="Y">
     <Warehouses>
       <Warehouse>
         <WarehouseName>WH1</WarehouseName>
         <Permits>
           <Permit>
             <LicenseNumber>R501155DK</LicenseNumber>
             <GoodsOwners>
               <GoodsOwnersIds>
                 <GoodsOwnerId>000000001</GoodsOwnerId>
                 <Items>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644839038</VariantSKU>
                    <Quantity>0</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                 </Items>
               </GoodsOwnersIds>
             </GoodsOwners>
           </Permit>
         </Permits>
       </Warehouse>
       <Warehouse>
         <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
         <Permits>
           <Permit>
             <LicenseNumber>C470413DK</LicenseNumber>
             <GoodsOwners>
               <GoodsOwnersIds>
                 <GoodsOwnerId>213456789</GoodsOwnerId>
                 <Items>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644839038</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>93</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                 </Items>
               </GoodsOwnersIds>
             </GoodsOwners>
           </Permit>
         </Permits>
       </Warehouse>
     </Warehouses>
   </InterfaceHeader>
   <InterfaceHeader Version="1" originationsystem="xxx" systemdate="2024-02-22T14:27:34" username="xxx" testindicator="Y">
     <Warehouses>
       <Warehouse>
         <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
         <Permits>
           <Permit>
             <LicenseNumber>R501155DK</LicenseNumber>
             <GoodsOwners>
               <GoodsOwnersIds>
                 <GoodsOwnerId>000000001</GoodsOwnerId>
                 <Items>
                  <Item>
                    <VariantSKU>5707644839076</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>300</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                 </Items>
               </GoodsOwnersIds>
             </GoodsOwners>
          </Permit>
        </Permits>
       </Warehouse>
       <Warehouse>
         <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
         <Permits>
           <Permit>
             <LicenseNumber>C470413DK</LicenseNumber>
             <GoodsOwners>
               <GoodsOwnersIds>
                 <GoodsOwnerId>213456789</GoodsOwnerId>
                 <Items>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644839076</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>2803</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                 </Items>
               </GoodsOwnersIds>
             </GoodsOwners>
           </Permit>
         </Permits>
       </Warehouse>
     </Warehouses>
   </InterfaceHeader>
   <InterfaceHeader Version="1" originationsystem"xxx" systemdate="2024-02-22T14:27:44" username="xxx" testindicator="Y">
     <Warehouses>
       <Warehouse>
         <WarehouseName>WH1</WarehouseName>
         <Permits>
           <Permit>
             <LicenseNumber>R501155DK</LicenseNumber>
             <GoodsOwners>
               <GoodsOwnersIds>
                 <GoodsOwnerId>000000001</GoodsOwnerId>
                 <Items>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644727472</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>468</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                 </Items>
               </GoodsOwnersIds>
             </GoodsOwners>
           </Permit>
         </Permits>
       </Warehouse>
       <Warehouse>
         <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
         <Permits>
           <Permit>
             <LicenseNumber>C470413DK</LicenseNumber>
             <GoodsOwners>
               <GoodsOwnersIds>
                 <GoodsOwnerId>213456789</GoodsOwnerId>
                 <Items>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644727472</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>4860</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                 </Items>
               </GoodsOwnersIds>
             </GoodsOwners>
           </Permit>
         </Permits>
       </Warehouse>
     </Warehouses>
   </InterfaceHeader>
```

How can I

1. remove the `InterfaceHeader` so it only is there once
2. Sort the XML file, so all the items that are in `WH1` comes first, then the ones in `WH2` (The License and Owner IDs are the same per Warehouse)?

This is an example of what I am looking for:

```xml
 <InterfaceHeader Version="1" originationsystem="xxx" systemdate="2024-02-22T14:27:11" username="xxx" testindicator="Y">
   <Warehouses>
       <Warehouse>
         <WarehouseName>WH1</WarehouseName>
         <Permits>
           <Permit>
             <LicenseNumber>R501155DK</LicenseNumber>
             <GoodsOwners>
               <GoodsOwnersIds>
                 <GoodsOwnerId>000000001</GoodsOwnerId>
                 <Items>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644839038</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>0</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644839076</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>300</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                 </Items>
               </GoodsOwnersIds>
             </GoodsOwners>
          </Permit>
        </Permits>
       </Warehouse>
       <Warehouse>
         <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
         <Permits>
           <Permit>
             <LicenseNumber>C470413DK</LicenseNumber>
             <GoodsOwners>
               <GoodsOwnersIds>
                 <GoodsOwnerId>213456789</GoodsOwnerId>
                 <Items>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644839038</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>93</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                   <Item>
                     <VariantSKU>5707644839076</VariantSKU>
                     <Quantity>2803</Quantity>
                   </Item>
                 </Items>
               </GoodsOwnersIds>
             </GoodsOwners>
           </Permit>
         </Permits>
       </Warehouse>
     </Warehouses>
   </InterfaceHeader>
```

I have tried this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="WarehouseKey" match="InterfaceHeader" use="concat(Warehouses/Warehouse/WarehouseName, '|', @originationsystem)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="InterfaceHeader[generate-id() = generate-id(key('WarehouseKey', concat(Warehouses/Warehouse/WarehouseName, '|', @originationsystem))[1])]">
            <xsl:sort select="Warehouses/Warehouse/WarehouseName"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it just came out like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: An XML document must have a single root element. Your example has 3 `InterfaceHeader` elements at the top level. This is not XML and cannot be processed by XSLT at all.

Comment: In general, it seems you want to group by `Warehouse`, not by `InterfaceHeader` as your attempt shows. But it's not clear if you want to do the grouping separately for each `InterfaceHeader` (as would seem from your code) or for the entire document.

Comment: Once you have your XML sorted with prober root, you can check grouping using the muenchian method. This is specific ment for grouping and sorting with XSLT ver 1.0

Comment: @michael.hor257k : A well formed XML has only one Element. The XML specification does allow for arrays at root which is not well formed.

Comment: @jdweng You could not be more wrong. On both.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : Did you ever read the XML specification?  I've been working with XML for a very long time and the specification allows arrays at root.  Not all libraries support arrays at root, but that is the library not meeting the specification.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I did. It says (in [Section 3 Logical Structures](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-logical-struct)): *"Definition: Each XML document contains one or more elements ..."*. And the word "array" does not appear **anywhere** in the entire specification. Now please stop bothering me with this nonsense.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it in the editor of this question, the source has a root tag:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml>

  <InterfaceHeader .........>

  </InterfaceHeader>

</xml>

Comment: @JesperHansen Good. So please clarify what exactly you want to group. Your expected output does not match the input.

Comment: I want to group all the items that are in the same warehouse.

Comment: @michael.hor257k :  There are two types of valid XML files 1) Well Formed 2) Not well formed.  You paragraph is just defining requirements for the Well Formed Type.  The specification was written by the IEEE (RFC) and you must be a lawyer to understand these specifications.

Comment: @jdweng Actually, the specification is issued by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C). And if you don't understand it (which is quite obvious from your preposterous statements), then don't lecture others about it.

Comment: I@michael.hor257k : I understand perfectly and have been reading these specifications for over 40 years.  The paragraph you reference is additional requirement for a Well Formed XML.  If any of those requirement are not met, the XML is NOT Well Formed, but still valid.  Well Formed is a constraint and not a requirement.  A constraint is a limit or restriction.

Comment: @jdweng I am afraid you could not be more wrong.

Comment: @y.arazim : Where in the specification does it say Non Well Formed XML is Invalid.  The specification uses the terms "Well Formed" and "Valid".  Well Formed is a subset of Valid as well as "Non Well Formed" is a subset of Valid.  If you don't believe me hire a lawyer.

Comment: @jdweng I am sorry, but your views are so far from reality that no intelligent discussion is possible.

Comment: @y.arazim : There are many applications that use XML for log files where there are arrays at the root.  It would be stupid and very time consuming to open the file, move to the end and put the new log entry before the last tag to make well formed.  The applications that use xml for log files simply append the new log entry at the end of the file.

Comment: @jdweng For the benefit of others, if not yours, I will say only this: by definition (Section 2 of the specification) an XML document is well-formed. If it is not well-formed, then it is not an XML document. In addition, an XML document is valid if it has an associated DTD and complies with it. End of discussion.

Comment: @jdweng I believe you are describing an *XML fragment* (basically an XML with multiple top-level elements). This is not an *XML document* and cannot be used as the input to XSLT (as correctly stated in the very first comment to this question).

Comment: @y.arazim : The XSLT library may not support fragments (not well formed), but it is still Valid XML.  Been using it for a long time and answered many Ops questions for Non-Formatted XML.  If you look at my solution I had to set the XmlReader Settings to Fragment to get code to work.  My solution works with Non well Formed inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for something like this (edited)?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="wh" match="Warehouse" use="WarehouseName"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/xml">
    <InterfaceHeader>
        <xsl:copy-of select="InterfaceHeader[1]/@*"/>
        <Warehouses>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="InterfaceHeader/Warehouses/Warehouse[generate-id() = generate-id(key('wh', WarehouseName)[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="WarehouseName"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </Warehouses>
    </InterfaceHeader>              
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Items">
    <Items>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('wh', ancestor::Warehouse/WarehouseName)//Item"/>
    </Items>            
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This groups all warehouses by name (regardless of parent), sorts them by name and copies all <strike>permits</strike> items of the group inside.

With a well-formed input:

```
<xml>
  <InterfaceHeader Version="1" originationsystem="xxx" systemdate="2024-02-22T14:27:11" username="xxx" testindicator="Y">
    <Warehouses>
      <Warehouse>
        <WarehouseName>WH1</WarehouseName>
        <Permits>
          <Permit>
            <LicenseNumber>R501155DK</LicenseNumber>
            <GoodsOwners>
              <GoodsOwnersIds>
                <GoodsOwnerId>000000001</GoodsOwnerId>
                <Items>
                  <Item>
                    <VariantSKU>5707644839038</VariantSKU>
                    <Quantity>0</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </GoodsOwnersIds>
            </GoodsOwners>
          </Permit>
        </Permits>
      </Warehouse>
      <Warehouse>
        <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
        <Permits>
          <Permit>
            <LicenseNumber>C470413DK</LicenseNumber>
            <GoodsOwners>
              <GoodsOwnersIds>
                <GoodsOwnerId>213456789</GoodsOwnerId>
                <Items>
                  <Item>
                    <VariantSKU>5707644839038</VariantSKU>
                    <Quantity>93</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </GoodsOwnersIds>
            </GoodsOwners>
          </Permit>
        </Permits>
      </Warehouse>
    </Warehouses>
  </InterfaceHeader>
  <InterfaceHeader Version="1" originationsystem="xxx" systemdate="2024-02-22T14:27:34" username="xxx" testindicator="Y">
    <Warehouses>
      <Warehouse>
        <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
        <Permits>
          <Permit>
            <LicenseNumber>R501155DK</LicenseNumber>
            <GoodsOwners>
              <GoodsOwnersIds>
                <GoodsOwnerId>000000001</GoodsOwnerId>
                <Items>
                  <Item>
                    <VariantSKU>5707644839076</VariantSKU>
                    <Quantity>300</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </GoodsOwnersIds>
            </GoodsOwners>
          </Permit>
        </Permits>
      </Warehouse>
      <Warehouse>
        <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
        <Permits>
          <Permit>
            <LicenseNumber>C470413DK</LicenseNumber>
            <GoodsOwners>
              <GoodsOwnersIds>
                <GoodsOwnerId>213456789</GoodsOwnerId>
                <Items>
                  <Item>
                    <VariantSKU>5707644839076</VariantSKU>
                    <Quantity>2803</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </GoodsOwnersIds>
            </GoodsOwners>
          </Permit>
        </Permits>
      </Warehouse>
    </Warehouses>
  </InterfaceHeader>
  <InterfaceHeader Version="1" originationsystem="xxx" systemdate="2024-02-22T14:27:44" username="xxx" testindicator="Y">
    <Warehouses>
      <Warehouse>
        <WarehouseName>WH1</WarehouseName>
        <Permits>
          <Permit>
            <LicenseNumber>R501155DK</LicenseNumber>
            <GoodsOwners>
              <GoodsOwnersIds>
                <GoodsOwnerId>000000001</GoodsOwnerId>
                <Items>
                  <Item>
                    <VariantSKU>5707644727472</VariantSKU>
                    <Quantity>468</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </GoodsOwnersIds>
            </GoodsOwners>
          </Permit>
        </Permits>
      </Warehouse>
      <Warehouse>
        <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
        <Permits>
          <Permit>
            <LicenseNumber>C470413DK</LicenseNumber>
            <GoodsOwners>
              <GoodsOwnersIds>
                <GoodsOwnerId>213456789</GoodsOwnerId>
                <Items>
                  <Item>
                    <VariantSKU>5707644727472</VariantSKU>
                    <Quantity>4860</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </GoodsOwnersIds>
            </GoodsOwners>
          </Permit>
        </Permits>
      </Warehouse>
    </Warehouses>
  </InterfaceHeader>
</xml>
```

the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<InterfaceHeader Version="1" originationsystem="xxx" systemdate="2024-02-22T14:27:11" username="xxx" testindicator="Y">
  <Warehouses>
    <Warehouse>
      <WarehouseName>WH1</WarehouseName>
      <Permits>
        <Permit>
          <LicenseNumber>R501155DK</LicenseNumber>
          <GoodsOwners>
            <GoodsOwnersIds>
              <GoodsOwnerId>000000001</GoodsOwnerId>
              <Items>
                <Item>
                  <VariantSKU>5707644839038</VariantSKU>
                  <Quantity>0</Quantity>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                  <VariantSKU>5707644727472</VariantSKU>
                  <Quantity>468</Quantity>
                </Item>
              </Items>
            </GoodsOwnersIds>
          </GoodsOwners>
        </Permit>
      </Permits>
    </Warehouse>
    <Warehouse>
      <WarehouseName>WH2</WarehouseName>
      <Permits>
        <Permit>
          <LicenseNumber>C470413DK</LicenseNumber>
          <GoodsOwners>
            <GoodsOwnersIds>
              <GoodsOwnerId>213456789</GoodsOwnerId>
              <Items>
                <Item>
                  <VariantSKU>5707644839038</VariantSKU>
                  <Quantity>93</Quantity>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                  <VariantSKU>5707644839076</VariantSKU>
                  <Quantity>300</Quantity>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                  <VariantSKU>5707644839076</VariantSKU>
                  <Quantity>2803</Quantity>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                  <VariantSKU>5707644727472</VariantSKU>
                  <Quantity>4860</Quantity>
                </Item>
              </Items>
            </GoodsOwnersIds>
          </GoodsOwners>
        </Permit>
      </Permits>
    </Warehouse>
  </Warehouses>
</InterfaceHeader>
```

Comment: Thank you!
It is close!   but it has eaten the InterfaceHeader...
and can it be modified to put all Item together for each warehouse? so the "Items" contains all the "Item" for the Warehouse?

Comment: You can easily add a InterfaceHeader wrapper, but I don't know which InterfaceHeader in the input should provide its attributes (they are not exactly the same). The same problem exists with the items: you can put them together only if you are sure that the LicenseNumber and GoodsOwnerId will always be the same for the entire group.

Comment: The InterfaceHeader wrappers can just use the first one, and the LicenseNumber and ownerID is always the same for each warehouse.

Comment: Thank you, it looks better and better!
For some reason it east the LicenseNumber and GoodsOwnerId?

Comment: That is not what I see (after the edit). You can see both in the output I posted.